# How do I get a friend's links with Facebook's graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I enabled all permissions for my access token, but I was unable to access the links of my friend.

I tried:
    https://graph.facebook.com/[friend]/links?access_token=[token]

Is this not currently supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get friends link by using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=friends.fields(link)&access_token={accesstoken}
```

[**Graph API Explorer**](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me?fields=friends.fields%28link%29)